# 2 Firebase instances in Android: One with persistence and one without

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We use Firebase as our database on our Android app. We have 2 types of data:

1. Static data, which changes rarely (less than once a week).
2. Dynamic/Live data, which keeps on changing on a second-by-second basis.

We have enabled persistence so users can access the static data even when they are offline. However, doing this causes Firebase to cache the dynamic data as well; which means that, whenever any part of dynamic data is queried, and it has been queried before, the user first receives previously cached, stale data and then gets accurate, live data.

We only want persistence for the data under static references, and not for the data under live references. Is it possible to either:

1. Have persistence enabled only on a particular reference within the database, so that the live data is never cached?
2. Maintain 2 completely different database instances of Firebase on android, and have persistence enabled on only one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SYNC` feature of Firebase. Just turn it off by adding `keepSynced(false)` and will do the job.

Brief Description:

Firebase synchronizes and stores a local copy of the data for active listeners. In addition, you can keep specific locations in sync.

Copy

```
Firebase scoresRef = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/scores");
scoresRef.keepSynced(true);
```

The client will automatically download the data at these locations and keep it in sync even if the reference has no active listeners. You can turn synchronization back off with the following line of code.

Copy

```
scoresRef.keepSynced(false);
```

By default, 10MB of previously synced data will be cached. This should be enough for most applications. If the cache outgrows its configured size, Firebase will purge data that has been used least recently. Data that is kept in sync, will not be purged from the cache.

[Link](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html)

Comment: 2 problems with using keepSynced:

Comment: 1) As far as I know, it still does not guarentee 100% that the data will be freshly fetched from the server every time; any data in local cache will still be given preference first and sent; afaik keepSynced() is a best service effort that tries to keep the data in the cache as fresh as possible


2) The references are too large and rapidly changing, so calling keepSynced() and leaving it on root ref is out of the question - resource consumption would be too high.

Comment: Whenever querying dynamic data, if I call keepSynced() only on the data being queried, would it work?

Something like
ref.keepSynced(true)
ref.addValueEventListener(new Value.....
........
onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot){
ref.keepSynced(false)
}

Comment: From the doc it should. my usecase for keepSynced() was different thought it could help you also

Comment: keepSynced() does not forever apply to the ref it's used on.  You have to apply it every time the app is launched.  It's equivalent to keeping an empty listener added on that ref.  If you keep a listener on a ref, it wouldn't make sense for Firebase to purge it from the cache, because the persistent keepSynced listener would just ask for it to be downloaded again.

Comment: Turns out this works practically. I used keepSynced(true) for when the user entered the screen, and keepSynced(false) when he exited the screen. This worked well for me. Thanks!